# Google Cloud SQL pPostgreSQL psql client connection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, database-connection, google-cloud-sql, psql

Followed instructions to created Google Cloud SQL instance with PostgreSQL db. I can examine it from glcoud command line with the instance name:

`gcloud sql instances describe my-fancy-instance-name`

I get back oodles of details!

When I created the SSL certs, it gave me the psql command to connect, which matches the instructions from the instructions given by [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-ip) on how to connect via public IP (I left that enabled for now).

Now, with the discovered IP and port, which was also verified by the gcloud command, I try to call psql to connect:

```
psql "sslmode=verify-ca sslrootcert=server-ca.pem \
      sslcert=client-cert.pem sslkey=client-key.pem \
      hostaddr=my_INSTANCE_IP \
      user=my_USER_NAME dbname=my_DB_NAME"
```

It takes a bit but it comes back and reports:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
    Is the server running on host “nnn.ooo.ppp.qqq" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port xxxxx?
```

and I verified the ip, but the port was NOT returned by the gcloud command...

Now, I have my SSL (.pem) files in ~/.postgress folder and added that path in my command as well, but no joy.

Any ideas why the psql can't connect (connection times out)? Especially since the gcloud command works?

Comment: The error message suggests that the CloudSQL instance is not exposed to the local host IP. 

As in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-ip#configure-instance-mysql) step 7, you need to add your local psql client IP to the Authorized network. Can you confirm if you did that? If your local host IP is dynamic, then you have to regularly re-add the IP to Authorized network once your local IP changed.

Comment: Following the Google [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-ip) you provided, I successfully connected to my Cloud Postgresql database from my local  psql client.

Comment: Yup - I was missing some dependencies - I can now connect. Sorry.

Comment: Which dependencies do you mean? May be you can post the details of the steps you took as your answer?

Comment: The error was actually just around needing to add our network into the connection tab in Cloud SQL for our instance; aaa.bbb.ccc.0/24 - nothing in the actual dev environment was missing.

Comment: Great! We will go ahead to add the comment as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message suggests that the CloudSQL instance is not exposed to the local host IP. As in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-ip#configure-instance-mysql) step 7, you need to add your local psql client IP to the Authorized network. Can you confirm if you did that? If your local host IP is dynamic, then you have to regularly re-add the IP to Authorized network once your local IP changed. 
Following the Google [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-ip) you provided, I successfully connected to my Cloud Postgresql database from my local psql client.